# AutoLayout to dynamically size UILabel Height and Width in Map callout?

Tags: ios, xcode8, ios-autolayout

I have to populate data on 2 UILabels located in .xib. This is used for Google Map SDK iOS for a custom callout (in map annotation). How do I set constraints in interface builder using Auto-layout ?

Here is what I have for now. I need to make height and width dynamic. Thus some callout does not include arrow icon.

[image]

How each label attributes looks like:

[image]

Its almost there, what happening is container view doesn't expand/shrink according to description label.

What are the steps I should follow to build this view from scratch (for the learning purpose as well) ? Plus different ways this can be achieved?

Comment: If you don't set any constraints, except for position, then `UILabel` will resize automatically

Answer (score 0):

Just change number of lines to "0" for label, auto layout will handle rest of the things. Remove height constraint because the height of the label will be determined by font size and number of lines of text.

[image].

Comment: If you are using TableView you can implement Self-sizing Table View Cells. https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells. In other cases you have to give frame to the container frame whose height must be defined either by calculating all constraints and height of label or any other means. For simplicity you can use UITextView.

Comment: Its resizing properly, there is no issue, but .xib and container view not resizing according to the labels.

Comment: Have you given constant height for container view?.

Comment: I have given equal width and height to superview.